# Anyone recommends 'Pure Variants' for Software Product Lines generation?

Tags: automation, software-product-lines

I am working on a software product line for online-tests automatic builds in coordination with my professor. He recommended for me "Pure Variants" as an open source tool which can be used as a plugin to Eclips. However, I am not really sure whether to go for it or search for other ones. So if you recommend this tool, then please tell me why you think so, or suggest for me another one you find better!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact pure::variants isn't open source but there is a Community edition for personal use. I think you should do a search though as learning to do this well could help your future academic career but you will only find one other tool specifically developed for *[software product line](http://www.software-acumen.com/about-product-lines/)* development.